# Upstart reload does not work

Tags: upstart

On a virtualised Ubuntu, I used the command

```
$ foreman export upstart /etc/init -f Procfile -e conf/development.env -u ubuntu -a my_app -t upstart
```

And can now start my_app using

```
$ sudo start my_app
```

However the following command fails

```
$ sudo reload my_app
reload: Not running
```

despite both of the following working

```
$ sudo stop my_app
$ sudo restart my_app
```

Anyone have ideas on how to debug?  `$ initctl list` also clearly shows my_app running

Comment: Good puzzle. Since `reload` sends a SIGHUP to the named job, I'd suspect that the pid file as defined in the upstart job is not set correctly. Of course this guess is confounded by `stop` command working properly. So I'd dig through the system logs for /var/log mentions of my_app and add relevant entries to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response @msw.  I'm working on this project again next week so I'll report back with what I find.

Comment: @Anthon slm rahmu jasonwryan manatwork The original SO question was flagged as being off topic for SO so I reposted the question here as advised.  Additionally I deleted to SO question so as to not be cross posting.  Can you advise me on where on stack exchange this question should then reside and also how you avoid being marked as cross posting after deleting a question else where.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: I just nominated it for reopen and asked that a moderator weigh in on it. Given I was the one that suggested you not-cross post and said this was a reasonable place for your question, I'm sorry that it got closed without my notice. Please do add the information I requested above to the text of your question; there's very little to go on as it stands.